# !ClrStack local variables - is it value type or reference type

Tags: windbg, sos

How can I determine if the local variable is a value type or a reference type?

0:000> !CLRStack -a
OS Thread Id: 0xf74 (0)
Child-SP         RetAddr          Call Site
000000000023e9c0 000007fef6b32012 ConsoleApplication2.Program.Main(System.String[])
    PARAMETERS:
        args = 0x00000000028f3c70
    LOCALS:
        0x000000000023e9e0 = 0x0000000000000000
        0x000000000023e9e8 = 0x00000000028f3c90
        0x000000000023e9f0 = 0x00000000000493e0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to identify is using [sosex](http://www.stevestechspot.com/) extension. The command `!mk -l` can give you the memory address as well as the type. Here is an example where s is a struct and c is class

```
0a:M 002aec64 004700f3 ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(System.String[])(+0x27 IL)(+0x83 Native) [C:\Users\nsrinivasan\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs, @ 90,17]
     [L0]:s:VALTYPE (MT=001a3884, ADDR=002aec70) (MyStruct)
     [L1]:c:0x0276c098 (MyClass)
```

Also sosex has some cool things that sos lacks.